# I need assistance with eregi - preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, eregi

I was getting the following error:

> Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/herbalhe/public_html/admin/includes/auth.inc.php

So I searched and found that I should be using `preg_match()` instead of `eregi()`. So I made the changes and now I am getting this error:

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'p' in /home/herbalhe/public_html/admin/includes/auth.inc.php

The code on that line is:

```
if (preg_match(".inc.php",$HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PHP_SELF']) || 
    preg_match(".inc.php",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))
```

Any idea what I should now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
preg_match("/\.inc\.php$/i", $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PHP_SELF'])
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me Cheers.